# Changes to Photos. Where did Camera Roll and Photo Stream albums go?

Tags: photo-stream, ios, camera-roll

In iOS 7, the Photos app has 2 default folders for pics.

- Camera Roll
- My Photo Stream

In iOS 8, the default folders is now:

- Recently Added
- Recently Deleted

How do you manage what's on Photo Stream and what's on your device?

Answer (score 1):

See...

- [iCloud, meet Photos: What's changing for your images in iOS 8](http://www.macworld.com/article/2359708/icloud-meet-photos-whats-changing-for-your-images-in-ios-8.html)
- [How to Find Your Photos in iOS 8 (And Where Is Camera Roll?)](http://mashable.com/2014/09/18/ios-8-where-is-camera-roll/)
- [iOS 8, thoroughly reviewed:Camera & Photos](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/09/ios-8-thoroughly-reviewed/9/#pics)

*extract...*

> while Camera Roll is gone, its photos are not. They've simply moved over to a different location in the Photos app: Collections. Collections, which organizes all of your photos by date and location, is Apple's attempt at making photos more organized and searchable.

It appears that PhotoStream has gone & only the last 30 days will be stored by default.

Answer (score 0):

to delete the pics from just your photostream, follow these steps....it works for me....lame though.....i wish they would give you the option to just have a friggin "camera roll" and "photostream"....

- Take a photo with one iDevice
- Check to see it in the Recently Added on both iDevices
- Delete it on one device (goes to Recently Deleted on that device)
- Check Recently Added on the other device to see if it is gone
- Check Recently Deleted on the other device to make sure it doesn't show up there
- Restore the deleted photo from the Recently Deleted folder so it shows back up in Recently Added
- Check the other device to make sure it doesn't reappear in that device's Recently Added

boom.... :)

Comment: now instead of two steps....you have seven......grrrrr...